# How do I log out of the Stack Overflow site?

Tags: discussion

Simple enough situation. I can't see or find any log out or logout link or button in any of the pages I've visited.

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[Tell me how to log out of Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)*

Answer (score 4):

Click on the Stack exchange panel at the top.[image]

Comment: Yes, but this may not be enough - also [log out of the OpenID provider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)  (e.g. Stack Exchange, Google, or Facebook).

Answer (score 1):

Scroll up to the top of the page and click on the StackExchange icon towards the top left.  There's a **log out** option to the top right of the drop down panel.  If you can't seem to find that, you can always clear your browser cache.  FWIW, this should be asked on Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, but this may not be enough - also [log out of the OpenID provider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)  (e.g. Stack Exchange, Google, or Facebook).

Answer (score -1):

Click on StackExchange, logout option will be in top right part of panel.

Comment: Yes, but this may not be enough - also [log out of the OpenID provider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)  (e.g. Stack Exchange, Google, or Facebook).